# Internet Explorer changes filename of a file containing special character from my web application

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat

I have a web application which support file downloading. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome. But for Internet Explorer, when I download a file with a special character in it, e.g.: `#`, it always changes the character to an underscore: `_`.

For example, the file `filename#.zip` will be saved as `filename_.zip` after I downloaded it from Internet Explorer.

The web application itself is written using GWT and Java. The web application is hosted by Tomcat. The IE version I use is IE11.

I know it is a little vague to post this question as I cannot post my whole web application code here. Any idea is welcome.

Update:

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mycompany.somelistener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>webApp</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you share us your web.xml file? I wonder what is it encoding? I tshould be encoding="UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

Windows disallows a number of characters in file names (`\ / : * ? " < > |` [source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506)) but `#` should be OK.

Maybe IE doesn't like it because it's used for web anchors (i.e. url#anchor). To find out what is going on:

1. Make sure the server actually sends the file name that you expect (look at the HTTP response header on the wire; use development tools for your browser or a local proxy server which supports logging)
2. Edit your code to puts all kinds of odd characters in the filename to see which characters are OK and which aren't
3. Try with a different browser; maybe Windows is renaming the file when the browser tries to save it.